# A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: No matching capabilities found

Tags: python, google-chrome, appium

I am writing a test for appium with python in the Pycharm, it throw an exception when I run the script. below is the script:

```
    from appium import webdriver
    from appium.options.common import AppiumOptions

    appium_server_url = 'http://localhost:4723'
    options = AppiumOptions()
    options.set_capability("platformName", "Windows")
    options.set_capability("platformVersion", "windows 11")
    options.set_capability("automationName", "chromium")
    options.set_capability("appium:app","C:\\Program     Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")
    options.set_capability("appium:browserName", "chrome")
    options.set_capability("appium:browserVersion", "120.0.6099.200")
    driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

*I run the python script and output result:*

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1534, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "E:\pythonspace\pythonProject\youtube.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 229, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 209, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 321, in start_session
    response = self.execute(RemoteCommand.NEW_SESSION, w3c_caps)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Stacktrace:
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: No matching capabilities found
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:1118:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:491:57)
```

I try to write a simple sample to open google website with appium framework, but the official site cannot find the example`